# Database design opinion with generic object

Tags: database-design

I have a collection of objects and I need to log their properties to a database at a regular interval.

Each object can have N number of properties and each property can be a different data type. Note that each object can have a different configuration of properties and data types.

Now the Datetime stamp is easy, but the Array of properties could be in a number of different data types (currency, integer, boolean, string). I know what the datatypes are for each property but each object (this can be inspected at run time) in the collection could have different properties.

I'm currently using Sqlite but will also have to support SQL Server.

If anyone has an opinion on a good approach on table design here then i'd appreciate it.

One approach I have is to create a header table with the datetime stamp and the datetype of the property:

```
[DataHeader]
ID (unique key)
ObjectID (int)
DateTimeStamp
PropertyDataTypeEnum (currency, datetime, int, etc)
```

Then create a table for each date type:

```
[CurrencyData]
ID (FK)
PropertyID (int)
Data (currency)

[StringData]
ID (FK)
PropertyID (int)
Data (nvarchar//string)

[IntegerData]
ID (FK)
PropertyID (int)
Data (int)
```

I don't like this approach as it makes extracting the data harder - not just a simple join - ideally I'd like a simpler approach.

Alternatively I could create a header table and then a sub table for my properties in the object:

```
[DataHeader]
ID (key)
DateTimeStamp

[DataProperties]
ID (FK)
PropertyID (int)
IntType (int)
CurrencyType (currency)
StringType (nvarchar//string)
```

The third possibility is that I could just convert all the properties from the objects to strings and save them that way - it would make life easier but is a bit naff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in a single table.

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [DBDataType] [int] NOT NULL,    
    [ValueText] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ValueMemo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ValueInt] [int] NULL,
    [ValueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValueDecimal] [float] NULL,
    [TimeStampe] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're describing variations of the "name value" idea - which has a proud tradition on Stack Overflow.

It's one solution to the problems SQL has with storing unstructured data, or data that has a variable structure.

Major drawbacks with name/value are writing queries with more than one "where" clause, especially with boolean operators. Imagine finding a record where the city was "Amsterdam", the value was between 12 and 34, and the weather was in ('nice', 'very nice', 'sunny').

Alternative solutions include storing your data in XML (native in SQL Server), or designing a table with all possible columns (if they're known in advance).

As far as I know, there's no "nice" relational way to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How FriendFeed uses MySQL to store schema-less data](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql).

They store the schemaless data as a single BLOB, in some object serialization format, or JSON, or whatever you want.

Of course this means you can't access individual sub-fields of your blob with SQL expressions, but you can create **inverted index** tables for each object property you want to be searchable.  This allows you to look up rows by matching value in a given property.

It takes some extra work to keep these inverted index tables in sync with your serialized object data.  But you should expect extra complexity when you go outside conventional relational database design.